# What are the elements of an approach briefing?

Tags: airliner, approach

I've heard that before landing an airliner, the pilots perform a mini-briefing to agree on what they will do and what they can do if something goes wrong during the approach and landing.

- Is this true?
- What is it called? (my best guess would be "approach briefing")
- What elements does the briefing contain?

Comment: Just to let you know, I edited my answer to cover "what if something goes wrong?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it's true.  Usually called approach or arrival briefing

Details will vary according to aircraft and operator but a typical list is NATS:

> **N**OTAMs<sup>1</sup>
>
> **A**TIS<sup>2</sup> notes, chart briefing point by point, date, frequencies, courses, minimums and missed approach procedures.
>
> **T**errain, minimum safety altitude, which route
>
> **S**pecial notes for arrival, taxiing, likely gate for arrival?

I noticed that you specifically asked about something going wrong.  The following assumes a serviceable aircraft.

According to operator, if the aircraft is not on a stabilised approach by 1,000 feet, a go around will be performed and the missed approach procedure (MAP) followed.  The MAP is printed on the approach chart.  The initial action is:

- to get the aircraft safely climbing away (aviate)
- to the altitude and heading defined in the MAP (navigate)
- then call ATC to let them know (communicate).

  *Aviate, navigate, communicate,* always in that order.

A stabilised approach might differ between operators but is essentially.

> The flight path is correct with only minor changes in pitch and
>   heading needed to stay on it.
>
> No more than 20 kts above the approach reference speed briefed as above.
>
> Correctly configured for landing (flaps, slats, gear, spoilers armed, autobrake set etc)
>
> Checklists completed
>
> Rate of descent <= 1,000 fpm
>
> Power setting is appropriate
>
> There may be other special checks for some types of approaches which must have been briefed as above).

The MAP might be something like:

`Maintain runway heading and climb to 1500' until reaching 4 DME.  Turn right heading 250 degrees and climb to 5000' to join the hold at DISNEY`

The MAP is unique for each approach so must be briefed in advance.

---

<sup>1</sup>
[Notice to Airmen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOTAM): Warn of recent changes, temporary restrictions, equipment malfunctions etc.

<sup>2</sup>
[Automated Terminal Information Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Terminal_Information_Service): A continuous broadcast of airfield information such as weather, special precautions, runways in use etc.

Comment: how about identifying navaids, setting comm freqs

Comment: @rbp I think I got those - `chart briefing point by point` and `frequencies`?

Comment: i get that, but the way its phrased it sounds like you're talking about it rather than actually doing it

Comment: @rbp Doesn't the checklist follow the briefing?